# HTML button which calls method in specific class instance doesn't have access to instance values

Tags: javascript, html

The below code will create instances of the ButtonToPress class and create a button in HTML. When one presses the button the expected behavior would be to log the class's variable n to the console, however I get "undefined" when I do this.

Maybe there is a better way to set this up? I would like to have the specific class instance tied to the specific button.

Javascript:

```
class ButtonToPress {
  constructor(n) {
    this.n = n;

    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.onclick = this.print;
    button.innerText = this.n

    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this.n);
  }
}

let buttons = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  buttons[i] = new ButtonToPress(i);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <script src="temp.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your constructor:

```
button.onclick = this.print.bind(this);
```

You need to bind functions when you pass them, if the function uses 'this' inside. Otherwise `this` becomes the window object.

[edit] as @Bergi points out in the comments, this is the button, not the window object. A jsfiddle to prove as much: https://jsfiddle.net/k3s4cmrv/

Another jsfiddle to show that you can access the Class instance by setting it on the button (don't know if this is advisable, but it is apparently possible): https://jsfiddle.net/r2uf6L5c/

Comment: "*Otherwise this becomes the window object.*" - no, it becomes the `button`

Comment: @Bergi edited, thank you